# pcolormesh with alternating cell widths

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to make a matplotlib colourmesh which is scaled irregularly to make some rows and columns wider than others.

Keep in mind that I'm not very familiar with matplotlib, and am likely overlooking an obvious solution.

Say I have the following code:

```
plt.axes().set_aspect("equal")
maze = plt.pcolormesh(arr)
plt.show()
```

Where `arr` is a 2d array of bits, producing a colourmesh like so:
[image: colourmesh representing a maze]

I'd like to reduce the width of every alternate row and column to compress the walls of the maze above.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**Edit**: here is a sample of the data. It's basically just a 2 dimensional array of 1's and 0's but I've converted it to a string for readability.

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   
0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   
0   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   
0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   
0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   
0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   
0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   
0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   
0   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   
0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   
0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   
0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   
0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   
0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   
0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   
0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   
0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   
0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   
0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   
0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   
0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   
0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   
0   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   
0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   
0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   
0   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   
0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   
0   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   
0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   
0   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: By alternate row and column, do you mean for example, row 1 has width n, row 2 has width n/2, row 3 has width n etc.?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. I know I can duplicate rows and columns in the original array to make some rows and columns smaller to scale but was hoping there was an approach native to matplotlib that I could use.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can't have what you're looking for using `mpl`. The best I can think of is to transform the data itself (rather than the scale) to get something similar, but without seeing a sample of the data I can't give something concrete.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll wait around for an alternate solutions but if I can't find one I'll just alter the data itself. I'll edit the post to add a sample of the data

Comment: Cool, should be pretty easy to extend that 2D array. ie. To double the width of every other column, first go through each nested array and insert a copy of every other value, then go through the parent array and insert a copy of every other row.

Comment: Yh, looks like that's the only solution. I was hoping to make alternate columns and rows significantly thinner which with this approach would be very memory expensive but looks like I'll just settle for alternate columns and rows being a half or a third the width of the other rows and columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`plt.pcolormesh()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html) can be called with either 1 or 3 unnamed parameters.  When there is only 1, that parameter is supposed to be the mesh data. When there are 3, the first 2 or the positions of the grid lines in the x and the y orientation.

You can calculate these positions by tiling the widths of the wide and the narrow cells, and then calculate the [cumulative sum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html). Note that there need to be one more grid position than there are cells. So, `34` grid lines (or `2*17`) for `33` cells. If the number of cells in the x and y direction aren't equal, you can calculate the grid positions separately.

Here is an example. The widths are chosen such that the wide and narrow cells occupy 2 units, which would make the axes coordinates similar to the example. You can use any widths if these coordinates wouldn't matter.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0],[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0],[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0],[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0],[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0],[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0],[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0],[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0],[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0],[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0],[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0],[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0],[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])

dists = np.tile([1.6, 0.4], (arr.shape[0] + 1) // 2).cumsum()

plt.pcolormesh(dists, dists, arr)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image: pcolormesh with alternating cell widths]